# Timestamps and documents are not detected in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch for a while, and wanted to visualize the data with Kibana. Since I have time-series data, I created a---from my point of view---suitable timestamp field in the corresponding index. The relevant part of the index mappings is as follows:

```
[..]
"properties": {    
  "@timestamp": {
    "enabled" : true,
    "type":"date",
    "format": "date_hour_minute_second_millis",
    "store": true,
    "path": "@timestamp"
},
[..]
```

I have played around with the "format" field-value, because I want to visualize data having millisecond resolution. Ideally, I would just like to use the raw timestamp from my application (i.e. Unix epoch time, fractional in seconds), but I couldn't get Kibana to detect that format. Currently, I am posting data as follows:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2015-03-10T14:37:42.644",
  "name": "some counter",
  "value": 91.76
}
```

Kibana detects the @timestamp field as a timestamp, but then tells me that it cannot find any documents stored having that field (which is not true):

> This field is present in your elasticsearch mapping but not in any documents in the search results. You may still be able to visualize or search on it.

I should note that previously, I used "dateOptionalTime" as format for the timestamp, and everything was working fine in Kibana using "simple" timestamps. I need, however, to switch to milliseconds now.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this highly ambiguous problem as well. No matter how I changed the mapping, Kibana simply would not display certain fields.

Then I found out it has something to do with JVM Heap size and Kibana being unable to display every field 'in-memory'.

Setting "doc_value" to true for those fields during mapping fixed the issue.

In the Java API, I'm building the following Mapping that includes the doc_values option

```
XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
            .startObject("@memory-available")
                .field("type", "integer")
                .field("index","not_analyzed")
                .field("doc_values", true)
            .endObject()
        .endObject();
```

Read More here : [Doc Values in ES](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/doc-values.html)